# Apache River documentation

Tags: java, javaspaces, jini

As it seems to me Jini is no longer available and it is moved to [Apache River](http://river.apache.org). There is poor documentation, and I wonder if there are some tutorials or other documentation for starting with Apache River.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The River page has a [Getting Started](http://river.apache.org/user-guide-basic-river-services.html) section that should help get you going.

Also [Jan Newmarch's](http://jan.newmarch.name/java/jini/tutorial/Jini.xml) page is a wealth of knowledge though it refers to the old Jini.org build but most everything is still the same as what his page says.

Comment: Thanks for directing to Jan Newmarch's tutorial. The old link doesn't work anymore. The new one is here: http://jan.newmarch.name/java/jini/conf/tutorial.html

Comment: Is Apache River still useful for RMI purposes? or it is outdated?

Answer (score 2):

River docs can be found in the release.  Jan Newmarch's book is the best for beginners.  The older books are Jini 1.0 based, useful for some insights once you've gained some experience, but obsolete, requiring you to use and extend RMI classes.  Jeri replaced RMI and is far more featured and flexible, exporting remote objects is now performed explicitly,rather than implicitly as with RMI.